# Help with writing a survey for clients to rate my UX performance/contribution

Tags: forms, feedback, surveys

I'm writing a survey for internal clients at my company to rate my performance on the UX services I've provided. The survey is going to contain a rating system on a scale from 1-5 (and N/A) in the following areas: Qualitative research, Quantitative research, Visual design, Interaction design, Workshop facilitation, Presenting, Writing, Information architecture.

I'm struggling to come up with the best labeling for the star levels. I want it to be obvious to the respondents what exactly they're measuring. What I want to know is what they consider my skill level to be. This is intended to help our new UX team to gather insights on our individual skills and our team skills to uncover gaps and areas we need additional training and practice in.

Has anyone else created a survey like this, or done similar research on personal performance? Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Although a bit contrived for this use case, you could borrow from the concept of "net promoter score" and ask people how likely they are to recommend you (to a friend) for each category.

Ideally out of 10, but 5 would suffice.

The concept of recommendation is quite useful to understand how people feel about their support of your work in the context of if they would trust you to work with people they know and trust.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your clients have the knowledge how them collaborate with your design process.

But you can explain, shortly about some topics, like the image below:
[image: Google Form question and description]

Opinion: Create a form with open question, try to understand their pains, needs, hear your clients. Numbers are cool, but how can you extract information about them? Thinking, Why the customer X, awnsered all this form with one start?

Answer (score 0):

write everything in the rating scale?

Poor X ---- Stellar X

it'd be:

1. Poor Design ---- Stellar Design
2. Poor Presenting --- Stellar Presenting

etc